# Geocode by IP in python and/or django

Tags: python, django, geolocation

What library should I use to geocode by IP address in Python? Is there something similar to http://www.rubygeocoder.com/ available for python? I am having a hard time finding anything that does geocoding by IP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What python libraries can tell me approximate location and timezone given an IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-timezone-given-an-ip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-timezone-given-an-ip):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> response = urllib.urlopen(
     'http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19&position=true').read()
>>> print response
Country: UNITED STATES (US)
City: Aurora, TX

Latitude: 33.0582
Longitude: -97.5159
IP: 12.215.42.19
```

Comment: I just tried the service for some Danish IP addresses, and the accuracy was bad.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) on GitHub/PyPi, you can get a full JSON object response from a specific IP address very simply by doing the following.

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.ip('12.215.42.19')
>>> g.latlng
(38.0, -97.0)
>>> g.json
```

You can also search your current IP address by simply adding 'me' in the search field

```
g = geocoder.ip('me')
g.address
```

Install it by:

```
pip install geocoder
```

Different providers might be more accurate then others, but it's functional!

Answer (score 0):

Try the GeoIP() object:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/

Comment: I saw that, I was wondering if I don't have to commit to some arcane installation process...

Comment: The installation should be pretty straight forward:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/python
They seem to have match.com,about.com as their clients. The only thing to investigate is the cost of a multi-site license if you need that.